# Powershell accessing SQL tables - permissions issue?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a Powershell script developed via the IDE.  It uses some generic functions in a little library to get a SQL table structure loaded as a dataTable, then populates the datatable rows before using SQLBulkCopy to write it to the database.  The script and helper functions file reside on a network drive.

Works like a charm via the IDE, and via a log file output I see that it is using my network credentials to execute.

Now I wish to have the script executed as a job step from a SQL Agent job.  The job executes the script as windows user SQLService.  I have ensured this user has the same network permissions to the script location as myself.  I have also ensured the SQLService windows account has the same permissions as me in the database.

When the script executes from the SQL Agent job, it fails to "see" the database table in order to get the structure from it.  Specifically the script fails when it tries to access the dataset $ds.  When run from the IDE, the variable contains an empty dataset - which is the desired result.  When run from the SQL Agent job, the variable appears to be a default integer.

I have tried a lot of things to get this working.  Within Powershell, I tried moving the functions within the main script file, adding Set-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted in each function, setting the $Sqlconnection Security to trusted=yes, etc.  Within SQL Server, I added the SQLService windows user as DB owner for the DB in question.

Again, the issue is specific to running from a SQL Agent job, it works as expected when run via the IDE.  Any advice is certainly appreciated.

The problem function is shown below.

```
$query = "Select top 1 * from dbo.Mytable where 1=2".
$SqlConnection = "Server=Myserver; Database=Mydb; Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=0"


function Get-SQLDataSet()
{
    param (
        [System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection]$sqlConnection,
        [string]$query
    )

    $ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet "dsname"
    $adap = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ($query, $sqlConnection)

    try
    {
        $adap.Fill($ds) 
    }
    catch
    {
        $err = $_.exception.errorRecord
        $err >> $InternalLogLocation 
    }
    return $ds
}
```

Comment: If you are using the a SQL task job, just use EXEC to execute your stored procedure. Is there something specific that you are needing powershell?

Comment: What does [it fails to "see" the database table] mean? What error do you get? What job step type are you using to execute the script?

Comment: Chuck - Yes there is a valid reason for using Powershell.  I am doing a variety of text file search and processing, with results eventually being inserted into a SQL table.  There is no stored procedure involved at this point of the processing.

Comment: Shawn - the "see" the database table is referring to the $adap.Fill($ds) line.  When I run the process via my credentials, the $ds variable gets loaded with the structure of the desired table.  This allows me to load that structure within Powershell and then write the rows to the DB table.  When run from the SQL Agent job (account SQLService), the $ds variable returns as Null, so my code fails downstream.  Sounds like a hidden permissions issue, but I have tried everything I can think of to ensure DB permissions match between the SQLService account and my own.